# Installing ubolts - How to push the slip joint forward

Tags: chevrolet, suspension, axle

I'm in the process of removing the lift blocks from my 2000 silverado z71. Now that I'm ready to install new ubolts I've realized that the driveshaft and axle have slipped backwards away from the transmission. As a result, the pin on the bottom of the leaf springs no longer line up with the hole on the top of the axle plate. I can't seem to find a way to push the rear axle forward so that the pin and hold will line up. Any ideas? I don't have a lift at my disposal, just a jack and 2 jack stands. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did eventually figure this out using a pretty simple method.  I tried moving the axle back into place using PetroEkos' method and also using ratchet straps but it was just too heavy and wouldn't budge.  The solution that finally worked was placing chocks behind the rear wheels, putting the truck in reverse and slowly rolling backwards.  With the rear wheels and thus the axle locked in place I was able to position it back into its proper position.

Answer (score 2):

I am a bit confused by your question, but I am going to attempt to guess...
If your actual axle moved back:
Put a block in the front to keep tires from rolling, lift the rear of the truck, place on jack stands, and use the jack(Assuming its on wheels) to maneuver the axle until aligned where you want it. The jack stands will keep the truck airborne, and then you can use a alignment tool(read screwdriver) to do what you need to. Remember to be safe when pulling on heavy parts.

Comment: Good idea but the axle was just too heavy to move using the jack.  Thanks.